# Recover QuickTime 7 Pro registration from backup?

Tags: macos, time-machine, quicktime, data-recovery

I recently had a disk corruption simultaneous with my Time Machine backup failing to execute for a period of 3 weeks.

So I wiped the drive and reinstalled the OS and have been dragging and dropping from the old back up to get close to the previous state. In some cases I've had to reenter software keys.

At the moment I am having no luck with re-enabling QuickTime Pro.  I have read Apple's note on the topic:

> [Retrieve a lost QuickTime 7 Pro registration key](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204589)

None of the methods they suggest work for me.

Does anyone know if it is possible to copy a preference from the back up to the new disk that will re-enable QuickTime Pro?  What would be the name + location of that file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file that contains the serial number, if you still have it, would be here:

`Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences/com.apple.QuickTime.plist`

***NOTE**: This is the main Library folder, not your User folder Library.

Comment: Too soon to award bounty, but that did it!  Thanks!!!